# PSEXEC remote to Win 10 - No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: windows-10, psexec

I tried to use PSEXEC from Windows 7 to Windows 10 PRO (not the preview).

```
PsExec.exe -i 1 -u myuser -p mypass \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx cmd
```

Output

```
Error communicating with PsExec service on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
No process is on the other end of the pipe.
```

I have only one admin user (myuser) on the remote machine.

I can see the service PSEXESVC.exe being created and running.  I stopped it, tried again, same result.

*I am using the same command and same config (firewall disabled, LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1) on XP, Win7, Win8, Win10Preview without issue.

Comment: Well I started a brand new version of Windows 10, disabled firewall and set LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy key. It works. :|  I'll leave the question open if anyone has any clue.

Comment: I went back from PsExec v2.30 (published: January 11, 2021) to an old v2.2 release I found on a website I consider trustworthy and it worked right away. I had the problem using PsExec on a Windows 10 2004 (build 19041.685) client.

Answer (score 0):

I almost gave up on Psexec because of this... but you might want to try connecting to Session ID 0 instead of 1. I've noticed some anomalies if (when...) Psexec ever gets hung up and decides to not delete itself (probably version related...) It gets 'locked' to SessionID 0 on the remote pc, and in my version 1.97, I am forced to specify SessionID 0 to interact with it again (or else reboot the remote pc). If running Psexec from script, you likely should specify SessionID 0 to avoid the situation.
Good luck!

Comment: Did not fix the issue for me using PsExec v2.30 on Windows 10 2004 (build 19041.685)